# Disassemble .NET IL to find error message

Tags: .net, il

My team is attempting to find where an error message is occuring within a .NET `windows service`, that encapsulates a web service, which was built by Microsoft and resides on our servers, to support a business product we use.  Microsoft has personally told us that the error we are recieving is in fact one of their errors, however they cannot identify where or why it is occuring.  It is a critical business process, causing much heartache to our team.

This error occurs, as far as we can tell, randomly, and has no comminalities that we can discover by looking at the stack traces.  The last call on the stack trace is our method call attempting to read the response from the service, giving us no hint where or why the error is occuring within the method call to the service.  The Microsoft windows service is not logging any errors to the event viewer.

We would like to trace where this error is coming from by looking for the literal error message string that is being thrown.  If we can identify the method call generating this error, we can be one step closer to narrowing down how to tackle this error.

While we don't have access to the source code to this service, we can however view the IL by using the IL Disassembler (idlasm.exe).  I have dumped the IL for a few of the assemblies, but their are no literal strings.

Is it possible to find a literal string within the IL?  I assume it's encoded -- I just don't know enough about IL to determine where to look, or how to identify a string within the IL.   If it doesn't exist as a literal string with a method in the IL, and is stored in a resource, where else could the error message be found?

The stack trace, with the app names replaced.

```
Raw Error:  There is insufficient memory to execute this function.
This can be caused by recursive function calls. Contact your system administrator.

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)   
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at Product.DoSomething() in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\da35f853\f48bba34\App_WebReferences.jygjwt-a.0.cs:line 701
at Product.DoSomething() in E:\Sites\Example.com\App_Code\File.vb:line 1105
at ASP.shop_checkout_aspx.ProcessCheckout() in E:\Sites\Example.com\processcheckout.aspx:line 546
```

A few side notes is that there is plenty of memory availible at the time of this error message, and when this error occurs, every subsequent call to any method returns this same error.  It will only subside by restarting the Microsoft services.

We have narrowed down every single call to the services used by our site, but cannot reproduce this message.  We can overload the service in development with about 1000x the traffic as seen in production, and cause an out of memory exception (by consuming all of the memory), but not the message which states, "`Can be` caused by a recursive function call."  Agian, which Microsoft states is a unique error that their product specifically throws.

**Update**

We have managed to find the literal error message within an `.etx` file, which looks like the following:

```
//   ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
// ÚÄ´  STACK  ÃÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
// ³ ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ                                                              ³
// ³                                                                          ³
// ³  Stack Manager                                                           ³
// ³                                                                          ³
// ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
@1@15@0@
@2@1@0@
There is insufficient memory to execute this function.

This can be caused by recursive function calls that are used in the program. Contact your system administrator.
@2@END@0@
```

I assume that the `@1@15@0@`, `@2@1@0@`, and `@2@END@0@` are some kind of reference that the assemblies use to reference these strings.  Does anyone have any information on how to tie these back to one of the assemblies that use these strings?  Thus far there doesn't seem to be any data in the IL dumps that match the format with the `@` symbols.

Comment: You could try to hunt it using [Redgates Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and the [Disassemble addin](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/). Otherwise I fear there's not much we can do for you, except if you provide us with the file and the stacktrace...which is most likely not going to happen, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Bobby.  I'm intentionally leaving our the error message and product as not to infringe on any Microsoft legalities. =)

Comment: One last thought, is the last or the first line in the stacktrace your method? If it is the first, the exception is originating from your own application, if it is the last it's in their application.

Comment: "The last call on the stack trace is our method call", is that Microsoft code calling into you? or the other way around?

Comment: @Bobby, unless it's actually an error from the framework itself?

Comment: We are calling into a Microsoft method outside of our application.  The error is being returned as a SoapException.  Their code isn't throwing the error and logging it -- it seems to be handled and passed back to our application where it is thrown.

Comment: @George: Could you please provide us with masked/blackened stacktrace (Application names replaced etc.) and error message?

Comment: @Ziplin: That could, of course be, but someone has to 'provoke' that exception, and the question at the moment is, is it the MS app or their own. Unless he found a bug in the framework...

Comment: @Bobby I've added the stack trace and error message.

Comment: @George: I'm sorry, I have no experience with web services, so I'm out. But this smells a little bit like a misconfiguration of `Product` (whoever that may belong to) or a bug of the Framework. Though, I'm unable to dig up information on `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse()`, but as I said, I'm trying to stay away from ASP/IIS/WebServices as far as I can. ;)

Comment: @Bobby It's not specific to ASP.NET -- just .NET, and the IL, where I want to find the error message. I would be happy to find out the error message is on our side, but it's sadly not looking that way, as it occurs within different applications calling the same service with entirely different code bases.  Appreciate your help though :)

Comment: @George: As I said, you could use the Reflector to have a look inside the application and even dig down into `ReadResponse` to see where exactly the exception might happen. Worst case is that an error is coming up from a native call and is only 'wrapped' into this exception, which would leave you with nothing but the MS Support (which is, imho, nothing). You might also want to double check the configuration of everything. It could also be a malformed SOAP-Response, which is causing an infinite loop or something.

Comment: You might try using Fiddler or Wireshark to observe the SOAP traffic directly.

Answer (score 2):

You very likely need to look at the other end of the wire for the source of the exception.  Don't forget, you're using Soap.  The SoapMessage.Exception property gets thrown inside SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse() when it is not null.

The exception text hints at a so-called Soft Stack Overflow.  Windows exception code 0xe053534f (googles well), thrown when interop code discovers there is not enough stack space left to run a function without causing a hard stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In a meantime, you can simply increase the stack size for your IIS worker, w3wp.exe (using editbin). The default stack size is outrageously small.

Comment: @SK We tried to do the opposite to reproduce the error, by decreasing the stack reserve of the .exe that is running this process.  Before we changed the stack size, it was set @ 1mb.  After throttling the stack down to 768k, the process will still run, but we get different errors -- not the error mentioned above.  We are still testing this possible solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a StackOverflowException. The missing server side stacktrace in a SOAP call is a dead giveaway.